# Creating an array of UIImage with NSArray constructor and get error

Tags: swift, nsarray, xcode6.1

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var image1 = UIImage(named: "wide")
        var image2 = UIImage(named: "square")
        var array = NSArray(array: [image1,image2])
        view1 = PhotoCollevtionView(outerFrame: self.view.frame, photoArray: array)
        self.view.addSubview(view1!)
}
```

This is very simple code but I got a wired error which is:

`Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(array:$T2)'`

at line:

`var array = NSArray(array: [image1,image2])`

These code were written in Sep 2014 as I remember, at that time, it works pretty well, no error reported. But today I reopened this project and run it, the error showed, and I have no idea why this happened. I found some similar questions, but none of them really helps me with my problem. 
Does anyone meet the same error before? 
BTW, my xcode is xcode6.1, thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Xcode 6.1, `UIImage()` is a failable initializer. That means, the initialization may fail due to several reasons. If you are absoluteley sure that your images named "wide" and "square" exists you can implicitly unwrap them:

```
let image1 = UIImage(named: "wide")
let image2 = UIImage(named: "square")
var array = NSArray(array: [image1!,image2!])
```